# What is the ~/.m2/repository/ structure for Maven/Tycho?

Tags: linux, maven, rhel, tycho

I downloaded the necessary pom.xml and jar files, now I need to organize them so Maven can find them, but I'm not exactly sure of the structure. Here's my guess:

For example, the maven-clean-plugin would sit here:

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.xml

I realize the best way to go about this would be download it on my computer and test it out, but I can't.

Also, would the same rule/methodology described in the path above be the same for any other xml and jar files?

I'm asking this because when I run "mvn clean verify -o" I get the error "The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is missing, no dependency information available", even tho the POM is located in the path described above.

Comment: Did you download jar files manually or  by maven ?

Comment: manually. I went to http://search.maven.org/ and downloaded each jar and pom individually.

Comment: You shouldn't do  that, maven  download jar files  automatically when you add dependencies in pom.xml. Before this, clear your jar directory under .m2  folder, don't add manually.

Comment: And what if I have two computers: one does not have internet access and must have a working external headless rcp application build, while the other has internet access and can not have Maven installed. I know what Maven intends for us to do, but I can not do that.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem above is simple, my solution to getting the build to work, is nearly impossible in my situation.

Change the extension of the xml file from

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.xml

to

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

Once I did that I realized that each jar depends on other jars, which are described as dependencies in the pom file. And since each jar depends on each jar thereafter, etc., etc., it'd be nearly impossible to get each jar and pom, for me.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I was going to mention is that you can command line push files into the .m2 local cache.

check the documentation here for more information:  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html